# How to pass type information via JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an endpoint which is generic, and takes an `IOrder`, which contains a list of `IItem`. However there are different concrete implementations of `IItem`, such as `StandardItem`, `PackedItem` as two examples.

I want my endpoint to accept an `IOrder`, but for the deserialisation layer to be able to figure out which concrete type the nested items are.

So

```
{
  "Order": {
    "Items": [
      {
        "Price": 1,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Currency": "string",
        "ItemNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "Price": 1,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Currency": "string",
        "ItemNumber": 1,
    "PackSize": 1
      }

    ]
  },
  "FieldOne": "One",
  "FieldTwo": "Two",
}
```

Should deserialise into an Order, with two items - one a StandardItem and the other as a PackedItem

However I'm not sure how to specify this so the de-serialiser knows what to do. Currently it just tries to de-serialise everything as an IItem, which cannot be done as it's an interface.

Code so far

```
public interface IOrder {
    IList<IItem> { get; set; }
    string FieldOne { get; set; }
    string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}

public interface IItem { 
    decimal Price { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
    string Currency { get; set; }
    int ItemNumber { get; set; }
}

public class StandardItem : IItem {
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PackedItem : IItem {
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public int PackSize { get; set; }
}
```

(Simplified for sake of question)

Deserialiser

```
public static IOrder Deserialise(string json)
{
    var orderJson = JObject.Parse(json);
    return orderJson.ToObject<Order>();
}
```

Comment: cant you just make the `PackSize` nullable? Another option would be to extend the interface -> e.g. a `IPackedItem`. Because as long as `IOrder` contains `IItem`s, you're not gonna get it to use the `PackSize` because it's not part of the interface

Comment: Also: `JObject.ToObject<T>()` has an overload accepting a `JsonSerializer`. You can implement the custom behavoir you wish. check out this [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Comment: There is also a generic version: [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm)